# Caculating the PSD using FFTW

Tags: c, signal-processing, fftw

I'm sound file that I've record using  the `ALSA' lib using following setups :

```
Fs = 96000; // sample frequency 
channelNumber = 1 ;
format =int16 ; 
length = 5sec;
```

meaning that I get 480000  16bit value. Now I want to calculate the PSD of the set of that to get something like :

[image: PSD]

what I'm trying to do is tto save the result as a bunch of double value in a extra data so I can plot them of evaluating them ( I'm not sure if that's correct) :

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main(){
    char fileName[] = "sound.raw";
    char magnFile[] = "data.txt";
    FILE* inp = NULL;
    FILE* oup = NULL;
    float* data = NULL;
    fftwf_complex* out; 
    int index = 0;
    fftwf_plan  plan;
    double var =0;
    short wert = 0;
    float r,i,magn;
    int N = 512;

    data =(float*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(float)*N);



    out = (fftwf_complex*) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex)*N);
    //Allocating the memory for the input data 
    plan = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N,data,out, FFTW_MEASURE);
    // opening the file for reading 
    inp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    oup = fopen(magnFile,"w+");

    if(inp== NULL){
        printf(" couldn't open the file  \n ");
        return -1;
    }
    if(oup==NULL){
        printf(" couldn't open the output file \n");
    }
    while(!feof(inp)){

            if(index < N){
                fread(&wert,sizeof(short),1,inp);
                //printf(" Wert %d \n",wert);
                data[index] = (float)wert;
                //printf(" Wert %lf \n",data[index]);
                index = index +1;
            }
            else{

                index = 0;
                fftwf_execute(plan);
                //printf("New Plan \n");
                //printf(" Real \t imag \t Magn \t  \n");
                for(index = 0 ; index<N; index++){
                    r=out[index][0];
                    i =out[index][1];
                    magn = sqrt((r*r)+(i*i));
                    printf("%.10lf \t %.10lf \t %.10lf \t \n",r,i,magn);
                    //fwrite(&magn,sizeof(float),1,oup);
                    //fwrite("\n",sizeof(char),1,oup);
                    fprintf(oup,"%.10lf\n ", magn);
                }
                index = 0 ;
                fseek(inp,N,SEEK_CUR);

            }
    }
    fftwf_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftwf_free(data); 
    fftwf_free(out);
    fclose(inp);
    fclose(oup);
    return 0 ; 
}
```

the problem that I have is how can I implement the winding function in my code ? 
and  I don't think that result is accurate, since I'get a lot of zero  in magnitude values ? ?
if somebody has an example I'll be thankful .

Comment: Three points

 * Your screenshot looks like Windows. In this case you must open your file with "rb". This should be done in any case to improve compatibility.
 * Test your code with known input (sine function with known frequency)
 * Also you may want to take the log of the magnitute

Comment: Then your code should work (You are only processing the first 512 samples).

Comment: You will get better results if you apply a suitable [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) prior to the FFT. There are quite a few questions on SO about this subject already, with some great answers, so rather than go over the same ground again you can just search for these.

Comment: @PaulR thanks for your answer I've would like to implement the transformation using  windows, but I just don't get it, and honestly I didn't found anythings on SO  ??

Comment: Also I note that you do not seem to have taken on board the suggestions  from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139974/fftw-on-real-data-sequence) - still no error checking on plan creation ?

Comment: @user877329 I'm using the while loop so I can process all the data that I got on the file

Comment: See the Wikipedia article I linked to above - it's pretty simply - just pick a window function, calculate the coeffs for a window size of N, then multiply your input samples by these coeffs.

Comment: @Paul R, I 'll do it I promise but first I need to see it working !

Comment: In English that's called "putting the cart before the horse"! ;-)

Comment: In the article they just explain how to make a window not how to to move it in the time domain !

Comment: OK - I've given an example as an answer below.

Comment: @Engine Try to increase N. 512 samples corresponds to 5 ms. I would recommend 10 ms to be able to catch lower frequencies. If you doubt your code: Load a long sample and transform it of a pure sine wave at 24kHz. If that works you can go on and implement overlap-and-add or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of applying a ["Hanning" window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_.28Hanning.29_window) to your data prior to the FFT:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    data[i] *= 0.5 * (1.0 + cos(2.0 * M_PI * (double)i / (double)(N - 1)));
}
```

Comment: so now I'll get the value of this 512 values in  frequency domain, and  should I just with my window to the the 513th element and do that again and again, and how can know which value accurate to which frequency  in my new data[] vector ? thaks a lot for you answer !

Comment: You apply the window function *before* the FFT, i.e. in the *time domain*, for each block of N samples. Then you apply the FFT to the windowed data, calculate the magnitude of the outputs bins, etc. If you are concerned about the absolute values of your magnitude data then you can apply a suitable correction factor to compensate for the window function, but for most real-world applications this is typically not done, or it is included as part of an overall calibration constant.